# touchesBegan not working on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, touch

I have `UITableView` over the full screen. What I would like to know is to find the location where I clicked a cell.

What I want to do is to show the copy option when any cell is clicked.

For that I tried

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches
withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //some code
}
```

but this method is not getting called.

Any idea how can I find user touch over `UITableView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want to show **`Copy`** option when any cell is clicked then you have to go for

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method of tableView. there is no need to use **`Touch event`**.

Using this method you can get the copy of selected cell using **indexPath**.

## Edit

To get the position of selected cell you can use **`rectForRowAtIndexPath`** method

```
CGRect rectInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

## Edit2

```
CGRect rectInSuperview = [tableView convertRect:rectInTableView toView:[tableView superview]];
```

Comment: @FahimParkar Use `rectForRowAtIndexPath` also see edited answer.

Comment: this is working fine, but think I have 50 cell & each cell of height 50 and I want to show option for 50th cell. Using your code I get location as 2500 however after scrolling it should be as 430 (for iPhone 4s). hope you go what I meant to say... and hence I was going with touch on UIView and not with tableview didselect

Comment: Its correct for getting rect area of the selected cell. If you want the exact point of touch and from that point you have to display the option view then you can proceed with my solution. One up vote for above answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect the touch location on a `UITableView`. For detecting there are two options for you.

```
1. Either subclass your `UITableView`
```

### OR

```
2. Add a `UIPanGesture` explicitly in the view.
```

`UITableView` inherits the property of pan gesture and `UIScrollView` by default. Hence by subclassing it you can override the gesture methods and detect `UITouchEvents` and on the basis of your location you can show the `copy` option. If you will add a `UIPanGesture` on your `UITableView` then you have to add this method in your `UIViewController` and detect the `UIPanGesture` touch events.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {

   return YES;
}
```

and your `UIPanGesture` selector method as below:

```
-(void) slideView: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {

    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            CGPoint touchLocation =[recognizer locationInView:self.yourTableViewReference];
            //Your Rest Of The Code.
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:

            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The view vibrates along x-axis. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In case of `UIScrollview` or `UITableView`, touches methods does not get triggered. Please read more on [Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html).
To get the required output you have to sub class `UITableView` and `UITableCellView` and override `[hitTest:withEvent:]` and `[pointInside:withEvent:]` to get the `CGPoint` in the respective view.
You can read more [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=640508).

Answer (score 0):

Create custom uitableview with hidden copy button and implement the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath and then on the basis of row selection unhide the copy button.

Comment: for me copying content is not a problem... showing copy option is problem... i need to find which location I clicked...

Comment: Thats what location mean here which row you have clicked right? If yes then you will get the index of row and on the bais of that you can display the copy option accordingly.