# touchesBegan(:) not working on tableview/scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, events, touch

There are some [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464211/touchesbegan-not-working-on-uitableview) but not related with my situation.

`touchesBegan(:)` not working on `tableview/scrollview.` `UITableView` or `UIScrollView` consumes all touch events and does not pass to the next responders. I have a base view controller and I want to receive touch events into the base controllers `touchesBegan(:).` In some sub view controller (extends base view controller) I used tableView. When I touch on tableView its consuming and no events are received in base controllers `touchesBegan(:).` How to deal with this?

I want the touches received into base controllers `touchesBegan(:)` first. Then conditionally, I want to allow sub view controllers, tableView to consume it or not.

```
import UIKit

class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touches began!")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 10 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
        cell.title?.text = "Click me"
        return cell
    }
}
```

In this above code, print("Touches began!") is called when I touch the view outside the table. But when I touch inside the table I want still to fire the print("Touches began!"). Lets assume tableview is taking half of the total view.

Comment: Are you use subclass of tableview/scrollview?

Comment: I am using subclass of base view controller. So subclass itself is a view controller but has a tableview. And tableview is consuming all touches.

Comment: what is your goal? `tableView`'s `didSelect` is not enough for your requirement?

Comment: You need a subclass of tableview to detect its touches. In viewcontroller class only return its view touches.

Comment: @Kamran no it does not help. My intention is to detect interactions in a common point (base controller class) and have some checking. Not only cell selection, even any element, sub element touch.

Comment: @RakeshPatel could you explain a bit more possibly in answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Above method use to detect touches.
if you want to detect touch of your tableview then first create one subclass of tableview and then assign your tableview to this class and then write above method to tableview subclass. In tableview subclass you can detect touches and above method will call.

To test just `tblview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` and check your viewcontroller `touchesBegan` method will call.

Update your class file as below..

```
 class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, touchedTableviewTouchDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: touchedTableview!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.touchedTableviewdelegate = self
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touches began!")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 10 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell
        cell.title?.text = "Click me"
        return cell
    }

    func touchesBegunInTableview(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //Here You can do any thing with touch
    }
}

protocol touchedTableviewTouchDelegate: class {
    func touchesBegunInTableview(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
}

class touchedTableview: UITableView
{
    var touchedTableviewdelegate: touchedTableviewTouchDelegate?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touchedTableviewdelegate?.touchesBegunInTableview(touches, with: event)
    }

}
```

Comment: But how to pass the events from tableview subclass to controller & controller super class? Please see my updated question to understand the situation.

Comment: To Pass it you can create a protocol.

Comment: How? could you please work on my code and show how. Thanks for your time

Comment: check i update my answer as per your code and just add tableview class in tableview in your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks. But this way does not call touchesBegan(:), Actually I want to receive those events in base controller. And still cannot figure out any better way.

Comment: I wrote a protocol. whenever touchesBegan called protocol method also called in base controller

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem in my code base. touches began didn't work for me because we have dynamic UI Components and I can't make logic for all the components. So I used two things to solve this problem

**1.** on `viewDidLoad() -> tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .Drag`

**2.** on `tableViewCell` Selection Method (`didSelectRowForIndexPath`) Resign Keyboard.